# How should I maintain the cart to avoid frequent trips to the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My project in MVC is an order carting project.
The carting is done with the following structure.
There is an order object which holds:

```
cOrder -> List<cOrderItem>

cOrderItem-> List<dressing>, List<topping>, List<specialInst>
```

I am holding it in `Session`. Is it the right approach to hold it in `Session` without losing performance. Or should I follow an alternate approach?

Comment: Could you clarify about what is that data you are storing in the session? Is it something that can change, or is it read-only cached data?

Comment: it is something that can be changed and read at a later point..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume what you mean by *"trips to the server"* you really mean *"trips to the DB"* because whenever are dealing with the `Session` you are at the server anyway.

The `Session` will do the job, however, there are a couple of caveats that might be a problem

- `Session` is not persistent, it's all stored in memory. This means that there is the potential for you to lose the session at any point e.g. app pool recycle.
- Given it's not persistent, this means that a users cart is only maintained within a single session i.e. if the users session expires they will effectively lose their cart.

One approach which I have used in the past is to use a client-side cookie to maintain a basket session, this means

1. It's persistent storage so it's retained *across* sessions (not just a single session)
2. Nothing is stored on the server
3. It's very quick

There are a couple of small caveats with this approach as well

- Browsers need to have cookies enabled
- Users can clear their cookies (as such, losing their basket)

However, I've found that these issues are very rarely a problem as most people enable cookies in their browser and most users very rarely clear their cookies (and the chances of them doing it *during* a session is relatively low).

Comment: Also, most server-side session implementations rely on cookies anyway, so if they are not enabled using server-side session is problematic as well (you can use url rewriting to place the cookie in there but that very easily becomes unsecure). However, may I suggest, instead of cookies use localStorage. More space, easier to parse and meant for exactly this kind of thing.

Comment: @StijndeWitt +1 actually overlooked localStorage good point, however, localStorage is only available on modern browsers (and not every browser support it). You could have a hybrid though i.e. check if the browser supports localStorage and fallback to cookies.

Comment: yup that is what most libraries do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.  :)

Placing stuff that needs to survive across requests in the server session is fine for smaller websites, but it does limit scaling; it will be more difficult to distribute the load over multiple server machines, because either the session would need to be replicated to each machine, or all requests from a particular user would need to be routed to the same machine. There are out-of-the-box solutions for this however, it is not *that* big a deal.

But holding stuff in the session has other downsides. The session timeout for example will kill all the products that were in the cart if the user decides to for for lunch in the middle of his shopping spree.

Ideally, these days, I would be looking at storing the cart locally, in [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). [Support](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage) for this is increasing rapidly. You would have some big advantages over storing it in the session:

1. Less memory needed on the server(s).
2. More scalable as there is no server state; each request may be
   routed to any server that has capacity at that moment.
3. No session timeouts killing your shopping cart.
4. Local code (Javascript) can access the shopping cart without having
   to make trips to the server and back.

Option 4 is becoming more important as of late. If you have your data available locally there are many things you can do with it later on that would be more difficult otherwise. Working offline for example could be done that way. You can fill your cart offline and only need to be connected to actually place the order with the webshop.

Comment: Actually concern about performance at client end..if i have to make some frequent changes i have to loop through all list in session and so at user end performance degrade...

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: localStorage is structured, so you would be able to access the right list easily and efficiently. Also, localStorage is per user, so no need to store all user's shopping carts there (as is the case on the server side). About the security threat, please elaborate. I see no harm in the user storing the ID's (or whatever) of the products he himself selected on his local machine. ALso, other sites will not have access to it. As with cookies, localStorage is bound to the domain of the site creating it.